# Prove convergence in measure (i.e., in probability) "distributes" over addition and respects nonnegativity.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Suppose $X_{n}$, $Y_{n}$, and $Z_{n}$ are random variables, with $Z_{n} \geq 0$ a.s. and $X_{n} \xrightarrow{p} X$, $Y_{n} \xrightarrow{p} Y$, and $Z_{n} \xrightarrow{p} Z$.

Prove the following statements:

1. $X_{n} + Y_{n} \xrightarrow{p} X + Y$
2. $Z \geq 0$ a.s.

**For 1,** I noticed that $$\begin{split} \{ |X_{n} + Y_{n} - (X + Y)| > \epsilon \} &\subseteq \{ |X_{n} - X| + |Y_{n} - Y| > \epsilon \} \\ &= \bigcup \limits_{ q \in \Bbb Q} \{ |X_{n} - X| > q \} \cup \{ |Y_{n} - Y| \geq \epsilon - q \}.\end{split}$$

> I'm not sure if this is the right approach to take.  Any help is appreciated.

**For 2,** we consider for each $m \in \Bbb N$, $A_{m}= \{ Z < -1/m\}$.  I want to show $\{Z < 0\} = \bigcup \limits_{m = 1}^{\infty} A_{m}$ has measure $0$, and I'll do that by showing $A_{m}$ has measure $0$ for each $m$.

Ok, well if $\omega \in A_{m}$, then $Z(\omega) < -1/m$, but we know for almost all $\omega$, $Z_{n} \geq 0$, so $|Z - Z_{n}| > 1/m$ for almost all $\omega \in A_{m}$, and this is true for every $n$.  By convergence in probability, $P\{| Z - Z_{n}| > 1/m\} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

But if $A_{m}$ has measure $\delta>0$, then for each $n$, $P\{|Z_{n} - Z| > 1/m\} > \delta$ (since $\{Z < -1/m\} \subseteq \{|Z_{n} - Z| > 1/m\}$), which contradicts convergence in probability.  Thus, $A_{m}$ has measure $0$, so $\{Z \geq 0\}$ has measure $1$.

> Is the above argument correct?

Comment: For 1., use $\{ |X_{n} - X| + |Y_{n} - Y| > \epsilon \}\subseteq\{ |X_{n} - X|>\epsilon/2\}\cup\{ |Y_{n} - Y| > \epsilon/2 \}$. The argument for 2. is correct.

Comment: @Did I wonder why I didn't see that containment.  Anyway, if you post as an answer, I'll accept.  I could otherwise delete the question, but someone already made it a favorite.  P.S. Thank you!